# Using git to merge a child branch

Tags: git

I have a folder managed with git. The `develop` branch is the central development branched used and has the following commit history:

> A -- B -- C -- D

A patch is released by the vendor that updates the baseline state of the files in the folder. The files have been significantly customised in `develop`, but I still need to check what changes the vendor have made. I want to attempt to merge the vendors files into my `develop` branch, so that I can easily view the differences and resolve any merge conflicts etc.

I have tried the following:

- Create a `patch_v1` branch from `develop`.
- Delete the folder contents in `patch_v1` and replace with the vendor patched files.
- Commit the changes. `patch_v1` now looks like:

> ```
>                  E
>                 /
> A -- B -- C -- D
> ```

- Create a `patch_merge` branch also from `develop`.
- Attempt to merge `patch_v1` into `patch_merge`.

At this stage I receive an error that `patch_v1` is already up-to-date. From what I have read, this is because `patch_v1` has `patch_merge` as a parent.

I feel like I am doing something fundamentally wrong here and not using git correctly.

What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

**Edit:** I was able to achieve the desired behaviour by creating patch_v1 as an orphan branch and then merging develop in while allowing unrelated histories:

- git checkout --orphan patch_v1
- Apply the patch patch_v1 and commit
- git merge --allow-unrelated-histories develop

Comment: Note that *branches* do not have parent/child relationships. Only *commits* have parent/child relationships. Branch names simply point to particular commits; `git merge` does one of three things: creates a *new* commit, and thereby causes the current branch name to advance to point to the new commit; or does a *fast-forward* instead of a merge, thereby causing the current branch name to point to an existing commit; or gives you a message telling you why it cannot do anything, and does nothing.

Comment: Generally, if you're getting updates *from* a vendor, you would create a "vendor branch" and put each vendor update into this "vendor branch" (i.e., check out the vendor branch, install the new files, add, and commit). You would then `git merge` the vendor branch into your own branch(es). Putting the vendor update into your own branch is the wrong strategy as it produces this kind of issue.

Comment: If I merge the vendor branch into my latest branch, it replaces the content with the vendor originals. So if a file has been changed in both branches, I would expect them to merge and not be overwritten by the vendors file. Files in my latest branch that are not in the vendor branch are also deleted when I do this. Basically, I want my branch to be the source of truth - and the vendor changes to fit in around my changes (including not deleting new files I have added).

Comment: `git merge` does not mean "replace my code with their code". It means *combine work since the merge base commit*. That might be a lot of work, especially if the last merge was a long time ago, so this can be difficult to do, but it's the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you were crating `patch_merge` it was created from `patch_v1` when it was supposed to be from `develop`.

The solution could be to create a new merge branch from `develop`.